# Ansible backup file name

Tags: linux, ansible

When I copy a file with ansible it backups file(wrote backup=yes). My question is about filename that is default created by ansible.

`config.xml.6634.2018-05-22@17:52:12~`

What does 6634 means in this filename?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the process ID of the remote Ansible process, as can be seen [here in the source code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/f57d1013ea7b2a47e13eea5e855879d32b35b10b/lib/ansible/module_utils/basic.py#L2433):

```
            ext = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d@%H:%M:%S~", time.localtime(time.time()))
            backupdest = '%s.%s.%s' % (fn, os.getpid(), ext)
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This added in [this commit](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/commit/123d54e736520c59d8c7afdcb1c6526df501b174) (Ansible 2.2.0.0) to improve the odds that the generated filename is unique, probably in case two Ansible processes try to overwrite the same file within the same second.